# Web scraping with Spotify API

Tags: r, api, web-scraping, spotify

I tried to get 50 songs for each genre and put them together in a data frame with the genre name, but I got following error.

```
Error : object 'res' not found
```

I know that the undefined object is causing the problem, but I don't know how to do with it.
Could you shed some light on this?

```
**Language:R, Environment: Exploratory Public**

    genres <- RETRY('GET', url = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/recommendations/available-genre-seeds', query = list(access_token = get_spotify_access_token(), limit=150), quiet = TRUE) %>% content()

  m <- do.call(rbind,lapply(genres$genre, function(x) if(is.null(x)) NA else c(x)))
  genres_df <- as.data.frame(m)

  colnames(genres_df) <- c("genre")

　get_genre_track <- function(genre){ 
    track_check <- RETRY('GET', url = paste0("https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=genre%3A",genre),  query = list(type="track",limit = 50, offset = 0, access_token = get_spotify_access_token()), quiet = TRUE) %>% content()

    track_count <- 50

    df <- map_df(1:length(res$tracks$items), function(this_row) {
        tryCatch({
        this_track <- res$tracks$items[[this_row]]
        name <- this_track$name
        genre <- genre
        list(name = name, genre = genre)
      }, error = function(e){
          NULL
      })
    })
  }
  tracks_df <- lapply(genres_df$genre, get_genre_track) %>% bind_rows()
  tracks_df
}
```

(Required library installation and user information are omitted)

Comment: `res$tracks$items` isn't defined in your code. Where do you expect this to come from? Is this supposed to be scraped from the page? When you inspect the page with Shift+Ctrl+C (Win), and search for "res", do you see anything? Why have you chosen this object name - is there a tutorial you are following?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the script you've linked above, `res` is defined as follows:

```r
res <- RETRY('GET', url = paste0("https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=genre%3A",genre), query = list(type="track",limit = 50, offset = numoffset, access_token = get_spotify_access_token()), quiet = TRUE) %>% content()
```

Whereas in your code, you seem to have renamed that variable to `track_check`:

```r
track_check <- RETRY('GET', url = paste0("https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=genre%3A",genre),  query = list(type="track",limit = 50, offset = 0, access_token = get_spotify_access_token()), quiet = TRUE) %>% content()
```

So don't refer to it as `res$tracks$items`, but `track_check$tracks$items`.

Comment: @Matchamin Great :) Remember to accept the answer to mark this as closed.